# dynamic array c++ without pointer

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is it possible to create a dynamic array in c++ without using a pointer explicitly(int array[] instead of int* array)?

ie. something like this:

```
int size = 5;
int array[];

array = new int{size};

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    array[i];
}
```

Comment: Why not `std::vector`?

Comment: You're probably aware of it, but could you not use **std::vector** for this purpose?

Comment: Related - [Variable length arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You would still have to free it manually, the only difference would be the syntax. Also have look at `std::array`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I don't get it. You're also implying that you could maybe somehow use a pointer implicitly? What does that even mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course, it is possible:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    [](int array[] = new int[10]) {
        std::cout << "array = " << array << "\n";
        delete[] array;
    }();
}
```

Comment: Well, yes - but it is using the required notation! ;)

Comment: This might do what OP asked, but it's kludgey. Seriously, just use a vector.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. The compiler needs to know the size of the array, so to use stack allocated arrays in c++, it must be specified in the declaration. I recommend you look at the [STL Vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) class instead.

Answer (score 0):

`int array[];` necessarily has automatic storage duration (in a function or class scope) and cannot have dynamic storage duration.

You can hide the pointer inside a class like `std::vector<int>`.

You could do something like

```
int (&array)[5] = reinterpret_cast<int(&)[5]>(*new int[5]);
```

to delete: `delete [] array;`

Comment: That's terrifying.  Also will leak unless `delete`d in a similar manner.

Comment: To delete it you just need the address of the first element, and to get that you can rely on the automatic conversion for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a [reference](http://ideone.com/4bxvT):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int& val = *(new int[2]);
   val = 1;
   *(&val + 1) = 2;

   cout << val << ' ' << *(&val+1)  << '\n';

   delete [] (&val);

   return 0;
}
```

But as you can see, this is not very readable and would be *very* prone to error.  Best bet would be to just use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use dynamic types from `std` library, like `std::vector`.

The type `std::vector` acting very similar to array.

Look at this [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).